# how to retraive elasticsearch index information with Html table in laravel?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

`create/insert/update/delete` if possible in **elasticsearch** with laravel  but if possible display index information in **elasticsearch** with **laravel**

Looking like this *MySQL query:*

```
 select * from table name.
```

this query convert to **elasticsearch** **Query** in **laravel

Comment: Do you want raw query in laravel? here is the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries

Comment: i not want raw query in laravel.

Comment: i want elastic-search display query with laravel like above MySQL query

Comment: This is full instruction http://www.fullstackstanley.com/read/simple-search-with-laravel-and-elasticsearch
Or you can use https://github.com/shift31/laravel-elasticsearch and https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch

Comment: Can you be more clear? Do you want to access the elasticsearch index information through laravel app?

Comment: yes i more clear